# how to align the item on android sqlite database

Tags: android

I want to align the item on respective column title,here is what happen,is there a way to align this or do i need to code it manually thanks

```
Name                       Hotness
Yan 10
```

My xml code

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"    //this is my column 1 which Name
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Names" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"     //the column 2 which is Hotness
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Hotness" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSqlInfo"       //to save on the database 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="get info" >
        </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're inserting the information dynamically, which it looks like you are, you're going to have to specify the LayoutParams of the row when you insert it. It would look something like this

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(SOME_ID_THAT_YOU_ASSIGN_TO_YOU_LAYOUT)
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TextView text = new TextView(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams l = 
            new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
l.weight = 1;
row.addView(text);
table.addView(row);
```

This should give you what you want. You will make sure you set the text for the textView

Comment: You're probably going to have to play with the width and size of the textviews before you add them to your row. And you may also have to add layout parameters to the row as well which would mean you could replace "table.addView(row)" with "table.addView(row,l);"